# Profile:Edit deleting Grid field data

Tags: profile-edit

I am using {exp:profile:edit} to edit users account details and I have added a Grid Field type to store custom data. In my scenario I do not display the data from the Grid fields in the edit form and every time I edit my details the data in the grid field is wiped.

Does anyone know if this is the correct behaviour for Profile:Edit? I know the updated Channel Forms tag states specifically "Edit existing entries, and only edit the fields you need. Fields not in your form will be left intact." but I can't find anything in the ProfileEdit docs about this.

Comment: "In my scenario I do not display the data from the Grid fields in the edit form and every time I edit my details the data in the grid field is wiped." 

You've built your own edit form, without the Grid field rather than using the default template that comes with P:E and uses the {custom_fields} loop in the template? I was wondering if that might be coming into play here.

Comment: Hi Jessica, thats right I have built my own form without using the {custom_fields} loop. I guess I can put in some hidden fields, but it would be better if I didn't have to.